# Is it possible to create a migration for already created table in Laravel 7+?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

I created some new tables and some column in existing table but I didn't create them with migration procedure. Now I want to create a migration for them so that other developer can tract. How can I do that?

Comment: You can write the migration as you'd normally do, but you won't be able to run them on your system if the tables are already existing. Others will be able to (given they didn't make the tables already). If you'd want to run them as well, you'd have to drop the tables made in the **non-migration** way.

Comment: You can make migrations the same as others. if you want to create seeders from existing data in the table try https://github.com/orangehill/iseed this package.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel migration is just keeping track of queries to build your database structure. If you want to build a table yourself and then run a migration for altering or adding a column/index, it will work. The only thing matters is if the table already exists. But if you move your project to another system you need to ensure the table is there.

just follow this, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns.